# Linear layout button clicks not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I implemented a relative layout which has got a linear layout and a list view. Linear layout contains an image and a button. Is there someone who could help me ?Click listener on both of them is not working.

[image: layout design]

Here is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_height="50dp"

android:background="#00897B"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:background="#00897B"
    android:layout_width="180dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1.9"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="Register an event"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/refr"
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:onClick="ref"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:divider="#2196f3"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

ListView lv;
Button bt1;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> d=new ArrayList<String>();
String mydata,name,name1,society,date,venue;
public String[] s1 = new String[50];
public String[] s2=new String[50];
public String[] s3=new String[50];
public String[] s4=new String[50];
public int[] img = {R.drawable.rty, R.drawable.sf, R.drawable.rty};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Button bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,webform.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or false

    if(isInternetPresent) {
        new MyData().execute();
    }
    else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, listclick.class);
            in.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}




public void ref(View v)
{
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if(isInternetPresent) {



        new MyData().execute();


    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
public class MyData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        CustomAdapter cad = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, s1, img,s2,s3,s4);
        lv.setAdapter(cad);
        cad.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        getData();
        return null;
    }
}

public void getData()
{
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://collegeevents.esy.es/abc.php");
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity=response.getEntity();
        InputStream is=httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder strbuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            strbuilder.append(line);
        }
        is.close();
        mydata=strbuilder.toString();
        JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(mydata);
        a.clear();
        b.clear();
        c.clear();
        d.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++)
        {

            JSONObject obj1=obj.getJSONObject(i);

            a.add(i,obj1.getString("Name"));
            b.add(i,obj1.getString("society"));
            c.add(i,obj1.getString("venue"));
            d.add(i,obj1.getString("date"));
        }
        String[] s = new String[a.size()];
        s=a.toArray(s);
        s1 = s;

        String[] soc = new String[b.size()];
        soc=b.toArray(soc);
        s2 = soc;

        String[] ven = new String[c.size()];
        ven=c.toArray(ven);
        s3 = ven;

        String[] dat = new String[d.size()];
        dat=d.toArray(dat);
        s4 = dat;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }


}


}
```

Comment: You don't need that LinearLayout at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the property of button `clickable=false` thats why its not working remove the same property from your button it will work fine.

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:background="#00897B"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1.9"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="Register an event"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: I added that property because I read in one of stackoverflow answer that this may seem wrong but it actually works. But in my case adding or removing this line didn't make any difference

Comment: try cleaning the project after removing the line

Comment: please try once more after removing the style of button. just to understand the problem

Comment: These click listeners were working when they were in relative layout. When I made a seperate linear layout and shifted button and image into this,click listener stopped working.

Comment: everything is looking fine here... i cant see any problem in this code

Comment: you are giving weight in horizontal linearlayout then set the width of buttons as 0dp

Comment: Still confused where am I making mistake. This is part of project and deadline is next sunday. I need to implement this as soon as possible.

Comment: its not good to give width and weight both for childs of horizontal linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are set to `clickable = false` in the XML file.

Another thing is that you have many XML attributes that are contradictory or useless. For ex in you list view, you have

```
android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

This does not make any sense. Maybe your list view is covering the Linearlayout preventing the clicks to reach it. It is really just a guess.

Anyway try to remove all unnecessary attributes, that will definitely help.

Comment: I added that property because I read in one of stackoverflow answer that this may seem wrong but it actually  works. But in my case adding or removing this line didn't make any difference.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you click on the button and the image? Does the app crash ? Try to set a break point on the click listener to see if it is ever called.

Comment: No nothing happens on click of these views.

Comment: I guess my relative layout is covering that linear layout

Comment: I found the answer. This time i made seperate layouts for list view and other (image+button) and it worked perectly

Comment: So the problem was indeed the List covering the Linear Layout. But you could not see it because you had a padding of the size of the LinearLayout.